# Ajax requests but doesn't get an answer form PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with a jQuery-function to trigger an ajax request on click. However, I don't get a result though the script should send a value via post-method. It looks like the PHP-script doesn't receive the value, but probably the problem is elsewhere.

Maybe somebody can tell me where the problem is.

```
doClick = function (sender){
var jid = sender.id;
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
       $('.jwin').addClass('order-md-1').removeClass('order-md-2').removeClass('d-none');
       $('.jobs').addClass('order-md-2').removeClass('order-md-1').removeClass('d-block').addClass('d-none');
          var ink = document.getElementById('ajax').value;

          $.ajax({
           url:"get_job.php",
           method:"POST",
           data:{jid:jid},
           cache:false,
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success:function(data)
           {
                //console.log(data.success);
                if(data.success == TRUE)
                   {
                      //$('#ajax').text(data.nurl);
                      $('#title').text(data.title);
                      $('#crp').text(data.compnme);
                      $('#descript').html(data.jtxt);
                      $('#jadoci').text(data.city);     
                      $('#jadost').text(data.state);                          
                      $('#connx1').css("display", "inline");                                                                  
                      $('#connx2').css("display", "inline");
                      $('#applylink').css("display","block");
                      $('#applylink').attr('href',"links?jid="+jid);    
                      if(data.url==''){
                        $('#applylink').css("display","none");
                      }

                   }else{
                      // Fade in
                      alert(data.success);
                   }
           }
          });

       $('#returnmobile').append("<a href=''>"+jid+"</a>");
    }
else {

          $.ajax({
           url:"get_job.php",
           method:"POST",
           data:{jid:jid},
           cache:false,
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
           success:function(data)
           {
                //console.log(data.success);
                if(data.success == TRUE)
                   {
                      //$('#ajax').text(data.nurl);
                      $('#title').text(data.title);

                      $('#descript').html(data.jtxt);

                      if(data.company==0){
                        $('#crp').text("Agent");                            
                      }
                      else{
                          $('#crp').text(data.compnme);                       
                          $('#crp').attr('href','company?id='+data.company)                     
                      }

                      $('#jadoci').text(data.city);     
                      $('#jadost').text(data.state);
                      $('#connx1').css("display", "inline");                                                                  
                      $('#connx2').css("display", "inline");    
                      $('#applylink').css("display","block");
                      $('#applylink').attr('href',"links?jid="+jid);                            
                      if(data.url==''){
                        $('#applylink').css("display","none");
                      }
                   }else{
                      // Fade in
                      alert(data.success);
                   }
           }
          });      

       //alert('More than 960');
}
};
```

And the PHP-code:

```
require "config.php";


$jid = $_POST["jid"];


$ipa = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];



    $query = $con->query("SELECT jla.title AS title, jla.summary AS jtxt, jla.city AS city, jla.state AS state, jla.company AS corp, c.name AS company, jla.url AS url, jla.id AS coid FROM jobs jla LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.id = jla.company WHERE jla.id = $jid");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

          $output =  array('success'=>TRUE,
                           'nurl'=>("<b>Does</b> it work? Yes!"),
                           'company'=>$row['corp'],
                           'compnme'=>$row['company'],
                           'title'=>$row['title'],
                           'city'=>$row['city'],
                           'state'=>$row['state'],                                                      
                           'coid'=>$row['coid'],
                           'url'=>$row['url'],                           
                           'jtxt'=>$row['jtxt']);      
        $quip0 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM clicks WHERE ip = '$ipa' AND job_id = '$jid'");
        if($quip0->num_rows < 1){
          $quip1 = "INSERT INTO clicks (ip, job_id) VALUES ('$ipa','$jid')";
          if ( $con->query($quip1) === TRUE) {
            echo json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
          }          
        }
        else {
            echo json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);          
        }

        }
    }
```

Again: the result I receive seems to be empty. Even in the inspect-mode in Chrome I don't see values that I'd expect, making me suspicious that the $jid value wouldn't be delivered correctly. Btw: sender.id works so far. I used to test this.

Comment: One possible issue is that `data` "...is converted to a query string, if not already a string." -- [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). But you've set `contentType` to "application/json; charset=utf-8". You might try experimenting with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sending json or expecting json at server so remove:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be several issues. One common problem is when the request is done from a different domain the server does not serve the request. Use `header('Access-control-allow-origin: *')` at the start of the file or the function

Use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) carefully

Comment: The request is done from the same domain as the file which is receiving the request.  But thanks for the advice.

Comment: Did you check the `network` tab in browser console your XHR request? Does the request pass the expected parameters?

Comment: It's status 200, ok. The request payload is jid=1 (when I click on the first element with id 1).

Comment: It's empty. That's why I assume that there is a problem when getting the jid from post-method.

Comment: In the PHP code add this after getting the parameter `echo $ipa; die();` This should return the id and the response tab show display it. If this doesn't happen then there is some grave mistake

Comment: I have added the code (echo $ipa; die();) after $ipa = .... with no better result. So it seems to be the grave mistake you mentioned if I didn't insert the code at the wrong position. btw: I have checked the sql-code just to be sure and it works.

Comment: Add: I made a little change to the code and yes, I can see the IP now. So this part works.

Comment: We are close. Now echo `$jid` and it should be displayed in the response tab in the browser. If this worked run the entire code

Comment: And this works. I get a response. Now that worked well.  Thanks to you and the others. 
May I just ask this one more thing: I get the results from the database, convert them into JSON. As you can see in the code I call them to be added to elements. They don't show up. Is there anything wrong when writing "data.title"?

Comment: You are returning array in the response so do this `data['title']`

Comment: K, thanks. Let me experiment a bit and I'll make it work. Thanks a lot for your help. You r great.

Comment: If you want to convert the array to object simply do this `(object) $output` then you can access it as an object `data.title`

Comment: Ok, just for dummies (and I apologize for bothering you): you mean writing something like 'echo (object) $output'?